# How to get this Bootstrap navbar to have correct margins and align left when breaking?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap 3 navbar collapse properly but still have two open issues:

1. the margins not equal:

[image]

2. when the navbar breaks, the icons are not left aligned with the text:

[image]

I know how I could add style fixes until I get this right, but I **how do I solve this properly**?

https://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/v83aj4cn/3

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-collapse">
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                    </a>
                    <p class="navbar-text">Company Name</p>
                    <p class="navbar-text">CUSTOMER PORTAL</p>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><a href="#">Contact Name</a></p>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">2016-04-14</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the hamburger icon to be inline with the text in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, I would just assume that all icons or text would be aligned. It looks as if it is unaligned.

Comment: Since I haven't added any specific margins, I would think that everything would line up correctly, e.g. the left and right margins would be the same and when the navbar breaks, it would align on the left.

Answer (score 1):

There you go friend!

[SOLUTION `JDSFILE`](https://jsfiddle.net/v83aj4cn/8/)

Regards!